# Clear Rails text_field_tag with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have the following datepicker field on a Rails application.
`<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control datepicker' %>`

I am trying to write a javascript function to clear the text-field when the 'clear' button is clicked. I tried `$('.form-control.datepicker').val('')` and `$('.form-control.datepicker').empty()` and they do not work. Any suggestion on how to make clearing fields possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found a way that works. 
`$('.form-control.datepicker').attr("value", "");`

For clearing multi-select fields, the code below work.

```
$select.val([]);
$select.find('option').removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with selecting the element - if you're using jQuery, `$('.datepicker').val('')` should work :)

Comment: I tried `$('.form-control.datepicker').val('')` and it does not work

Comment: Just tried `$('.datepicker').val('')` and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when using a framework there is something nested. Try this.

$('.form-control.datepicker').html("")

If that doesn't work. try this one.

$('.form-control.datepicker').text("")